# Oracle SQL MAX() and MIN() with string

Tags: sql, oracle, max, min

I'm having an issue retrieving the MAX number from database.
The catch is that the numbers are in string format since they contain an underscore.

Example case:
I have 3 numbers in the database:

123456_1,
123456_2,
123456_13,

The MAX number I would like to fetch is 123456_13 (basically the biggest after underscore), but since they are string, Oracle processes them alphabetically and orders ascending as:

1. 123456_1
2. 123456_13
3. 123456_2

making 123456_2 the MAX.

This would be possible, if I would not need to display the actual MAX or MIN number by replacing the underscore and converting to number:

```
SELECT
  MAX(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(number,'_',''))) max_nr,
  MIN(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(number,'_',''))) min_nr
FROM
...
```

This would return
12345613 max_nr
1234561  min_nr
from my 3 examples, but I need to fetch the actual numbers with underscore and display that.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(number,'_','')))`

Comment: Or put your condition in the WHERE clause if you want to get the first entry only. SELECT number FROM...WHERE REPLACE(number,...) = (SELECT MAX(REPLACE(number,...)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the min and max at the same time, you could use the `keep` syntax twice, ordering by the numeric equivalent of all characters after the underscore:

```
select
  max(your_number)
    keep (dense_rank last
      order by to_number(substr(your_number, instr(your_number, '_') + 1))
    ) as max_number,
  min(your_number)
    keep (dense_rank first
      order by to_number(substr(your_number, instr(your_number, '_') + 1))
    ) as min_number
from your_table
```

| MAX_NUMBER | MIN_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 123456_13 | 123456_1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vtQfAqe8)

The `instr(your_number, '_')` gives the position of the underscore; `substr(your_number, instr(your_number, '_') + 1)` gives you everything after that underscore.

That would work if the values weren't always the same number of digits before the underscore, which could be a problem if you just remove it.

Comment: thanks, this pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REPLACE` in `ORDER BY` statement and `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW`

```
select *
from T
order by TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(N,'_')) desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

[SQLize - online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle19/c9795668535db13ec7ab7fe871d23249/)